# How to get input of string with space and put it in variables separate?

Tags: c

I got stuck with this, i can't figure out when set input. Example -> "LEMON TREE",  (there i set that(input) to read it double time function `getline`), it give me wrong output like "LEMON TRE E" down i explain this more, question is how i can change code for `getline`(mine modified function) and get output separate, here is my function `getline`, and here is visual what i want.
I use function from k&r-ansii book(little modified):

```
int getline(char *line, int len)
{

   int i,c;
   for ( i =0;i<len-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n';i++)
     *line++ = c;

   if ( c == '\n')
   {
     i++;
     *line++ = '\n';
     *line = '\0';
               }

    return i;
}
```

And this is visual what i want:

```
char line_1[10];
char line_2[10];
getline(line_1, 10);
getline(line_2, 10);

printf("line_1: %s ", line_1);
printf("line_2: %s", line_2);
```

INPUT: LEMON TREE // This is input in one line like u see.
OUTPUT: line_1: LEMON TRE line_2: E

1. What i need to change in my code?
2. When i write getline in header it say that it got previous declared, now when i use ubuntu, but before when was on windows i declared that and mix also with lib stdio.h and it have worked all right.

UPDATE: I want to change my function, that it can work with more words than two(to make it universal) .

Comment: 1) `char line_1[10];` --> `char line_1[16];`, `LEMON TREE`(10 char) + NUL(1 char). need size >= 11

Comment: 2) [getline](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man3/getline.3.html) as GNU libraries(`<stdin.h>`)(or POSIX) already exist. use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for whitespaces (eg. space) as well to determine where the word ends

```
for ( i =0;i<len-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n' && c!=' ';i++) {
    *line++ = c;
}
```

/*EDIT: (thanks to BLUEPIXY's comment for reminding me) Alyways use string (or other data type) large enough to contain possible input/value assigned to it.
*/

as for universality of the function you can either call getline in a cycle and use its return value to determine whether the last word was already read or use multidimensional array

```
while (getline(line_1, 10)!= -1) {
    printf("line_1: %s ", line_1);
}
```

Don't forget to edit return value of the function (I'm used to assign values that are are impossible to be returned any other way (usually negative values mean error while counting something):

```
if ((c == EOF) ||(c == '\n')) {
    i = -1;
}
```

also

```
if ( c == '\n')
   {
     i++;
     *line++ = '\n';
     *line = '\0';
               }
```

should be simply replaced with

```
*line = '\0'; //every string needs to be finalized
```

as for 2nd question, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ stdio.h does not contain getline function

Comment: Why then that error message show up for getline function? i only #include <stdio.h>

Comment: I set that if ( c == '\n') { i++; *line++= '\n' .... because if c == EOF, there is required to set '\n' , and '\0';